# How to take elasped time with nanosecond precision in Java 9

Tags: java, multithreading, time

Does java 9 provide nanosecond precision? Is it possible now to take elapsed time with nano second precision in java 9.

I have a Java Process that on receiving a message, sends a message back ... I want to measure the Precise time taken by the Java process from the time it received the message to the time it write the message back to the TCP socket(Its a TCP socket Program) with  at least microseconds precision . I was expecting the System.currentTimeMillis() or some similar API call will have that nanosecond precision system time in Java 9 (have read something like that https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730)

Comment: Well `System.nanoTime` will give you nanosecond *precision*. Whether it will give you nanosecond *accuracy* is a different matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet it will not and this hasn't changed in java-9 and I doubt this is java related - it still takes time to execute `System.nanoTime`, more then a nano-second

Comment: put your comment to Kayaman's answer in the question, not as a comment

Comment: Sorry . Ok Done editing my question .. and thanks for the comments

Comment: Update : I have not tested this on java 9 . But this Jdk 9 bug id seems to be related to what I have asked. [https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8164428].

Answer (score 4):

`System.nanoTime()` has been around since Java 5.

> This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily
>   nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes)
>   - no guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as that of `currentTimeMillis()`.

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
...
long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
```

If you intend to use it for benchmarking, don't. Use a proper test harness instead.

Comment: Yes But in my experience it not suitable for taking elapsed time of a process .. I have requirement to measure the time taken by a process to at least microseconds precision.  Or put it in other words Is it possible to pause a thread for nanoseconds in Java9 .. Because upto java 8 a sleep will only resolve to milliseconds.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @ArunViswanathan `LockSupport.parkNanos`

Comment: I have a Java Process that on receiving a message, sends a message back ... I want to measure the Precise time taken by the Java process from the time it received the message to the time it write the message back to the TCP socket(Its a TCP socket Program) . I was expecting the System.currentTimeMillis() or some similar API call will have that nanosecond precision system time in Java 9 (have read something like that https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730)

Comment: @ArunViswanathan it will not - the best you can get is `System.nanoTime` - which is documented to measure *elapsed time*

Answer (score 1):

Seems that this is entirely un-related with the question per-se and you are really looking for `LockSupport.parkNanos`, that will give nano-second precision to make a Thread park.